# What's the partial derivative of this expression?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

How do I show that $\dfrac{\partial{x'Ax}}{\partial{x_i}} = 2(Ax)_i$, where $x$ is an $n\times1$ column vector and $A$ is a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix. Any *lucid* and *memorable* proof?

Comment: It isn't ${}{}$

Comment: What do you mean?@user251257

Comment: The statement is wrong if $A\ne 0$. Check it for $n=1$.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks, edited.

Comment: Now, check a **non symmetric** $2\times 2$ matrix $A$.

Comment: @user251257 You're right. $A$ is a covariance matrix and is symmetric, re-edited.

Comment: As for the proof, just apply product rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i remember this by using the total derivative of the expression:

$$d(x'Ax)=dx'Ax+x'Adx$$.

The expressions are scalars (easy to check by format inspection) so transposing the second expression will not change it. Also remember that transposing changes the order of terms.

$$d(x'Ax)=dx'Ax+dx'A'x=dx'(A+A')x$$

As A is symmetric (A'=A) we obtain:

$$d(x'Ax)=dx'(2Ax)$$.

Now remember that the total derivative can be written as the dot product of the gradient and the infinitesimal vector dx. Hence, the expression $2Ax$ is the gradient (what you were looking for).